# How to search for a specific cells and change their value by VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA in Excel. I was asked to make a distribution system to distribute customers to agents. I have a table contains Agents, rank and assigned total. The user select the city from user form and based on the selection the customer is assigned to the agent that has the smallest rank. So if user select London system search for agent that has smallest rank in London and then increase number of assign by 1 for that agent.

I try to write the code but am facing run time error, I know that I have a lot of mistakes in the if then part. The comment line I did know how to write the right code to apply the action I want.

```
Sub DistSystem()

Dim count As Integer
Dim City As String
Dim minmum As Long
Dim i As Integer

Dim array_rank() As Variant
Dim array_city() As Variant
Dim array_assign() As Variant

count = Sheets("111").Range("Y2").Value
City = Sheets("111").Range("W2").Value

array_city = Range("A1:A" & count).Value
array_rank = Range("E1:E" & count).Value
array_assign = Range("F1:F" & count).Value       

minmum = 1000000
i = 1

Do

    If City = array_city(i) And array_rank(i) <= minmum Then
        minmum = array_rank(i)    
    Else
        i = i + 1    
    End If

Loop While i <= count

MsgBox (minmum)

i = 1

Do

    If City = array_city(i) And minmum = array_rank(i) And Then

    'Here I want to apply an action: seting the new value by 
    ' incresing the assign number for the smallest rank

        array_assign(i) = array_assign(i) + 1

    Else    
        i = i + 1    
    End If

Loop While i <= count

End Sub
```

Comment: It will help if you say in the question what error you are getting.  I can see one problem in your code: think about what happens to `i` when you get to the commented line.

Comment: The problem may have something to do with the `Loop While i <= count` at the end of your procedure. What are you trying to get that loop to do?

Comment: I'm getting run time error in the first loop. The first loop is locking for the minimum rank of selected city and store the minimum rank found in variable minimum. The second loop is for updating the number of assign number for the agent that have smallest rank. count is variable that contains number of records.

Comment: The problem start with the If condition in the first loop

Comment: @user3333621 you didn't even read the last paragraph of [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24032807/250725) to your earlier question

Comment: @psubsee Dear I read all your answer, sorry if theirs a part that I didnt understand. I change the required and it's work well for the part I ask for.

Comment: @user3333621 see my answer.  You missed a section on how to access the values in the array.  Sorry if it wasn't clear enough when written, but if something I said in that answer or this one isn't clear or understandable, do not be afraid to ask for clarification.  That's what comments are for.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is with `If City = array_city(i) And array_rank(i) <= minmum Then`

Because you are reading the entire range into an array as you are, the resulting array is 2 dimensions, so to reference the values, you need to have **both** dimensions.

The reason you are getting the error is `array_city(i)` and `array_rank(i)` simply do not exist, so you end up with a "Runtime Error:Subscript of our range."

To [quote myself](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24032807/250725):

> The resulting array with be 2 dimensions, with the Row value as the first dimension and the column as the 2nd dimension. since all of the ranges are a single column, you would access any value by calling array_rank(Row,1) or array_city(Row,1) or array_assign(Row,1).

And as [aucuparia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3590073/aucuparia) astutely points out, your `i = i + 1` needs to be outside of the if statement, otherwise, once you get to an `i` value that meets the first condition, `i` will never increment again and you'll be stuck in an infinite loop.

The if statement should read:

```
If City = array_city(i,1) And array_rank(i,1) <= minmum Then
    minmum = array_rank(i,1)    
End If
i = i + 1
```

Likewise, anywhere else you are referencing `array_city`, `array_rank` and `array_assign` you need to use the same syntax.

Comment: Oh thank you I got what you mean, but when I change the syntax and run the code its hold and not responding

Comment: @user3333621 you are very likely in an infinite loop.  If `i` is never larger than `count` you will never break out of the loop.  We can't see your data, so I have no idea if it is possible for i never to increase enough to exceed the count parameter.

Comment: I upload the file to dropbox here's the link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uwtwvlcsn8tsev6/Leads%20Dist%20monthly%20-%20last%20edit1.xlsm

Comment: Just take `i=i+1` outside the `if` statement in each loop.  You always want to increment `i`, otherwise each loop will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: @user3333621 please take a look at the edited answer.  One of the comments here saw the issue before I had a chance to really did into it,

Comment: @psubsee2003 got it so I take the increment statement outside as @aucuparia said and its work well thank you so much. But still face some difficulties in the second loop I add this statement `array_assign(i,1) = array_assign(i,1) + 1`
and `Range("F" & i).Value = array_assign(i,1) ` inside the `if` statement to increment the `assign` by 1 and then update the cell contain the old number by the new `assign` number. But its not work, its doesn't increment.

Comment: I believe the problem is in `Range("F" & i).Value = array_assign(i,1)` I check for new value is increased but not changed in cell

Comment: @psubee2003 finaly done I do it is working well now thank you all